# POST-запрос добавления записи в массив (sequelize)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

У меня есть `user`, у которого есть поле `posts` с типом `array`. Как мне сделать post-запрос на добавление нового поста в массив? Подскажите пожалуйста. Вот мой теперешний код:

```
exports.addPost = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ where: { posts: req.body.comment } })
    .then(users => {
      console.log("asd")
      users.posts.push(req.body.comment);
      response.status(200, { message: 'added' }, res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      response.status(400, error, res);
      res.send({ message: error });
    });
};
```

Comment: а бд какая?....

Comment: база данных mysql